# How the unit test should be written?

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I want to write a unit test for a directive as below:

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
    .directive('myDirective', ['$window','MyConfig', function($window,MyConfig){
    return {
        link: function(scope, element, attr, controller) {

            var w = angular.element($window);
            var top = 70;
            function adjustTop(){
                var oldtop = scope.top;
                var newtop = top - w.scrollTop();
                if(newtop>15){
                    scope.top = newtop;
                }else{
                    scope.top = 15;
                }

                if(oldtop!=newtop){
                    scope.$apply();
                }
            }

            if(MyConfig.adjusttop){
                w.bind('scroll', function () {
                    adjustTop();
                });
                adjustTop();
            }else{
                scope.top = 15;
            };

        }
    };
}]);



describe('myDirective:', function () {
    it("should perform adjust top position only when MyConfig.adjusttop is true",function(){
        // how to write the test here?
    });
});
```

How should I write the unit test to confirm top position is only adjusted when `MyConfig.adjusttop` is set to true? Can I use `spyOn` to detect `adjustTop()` function ever to be called? If can, how to use it?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot spyOn adjustTop because it is "private" to the link function.  You can, however, test that scope.top changes as you would expect.

You would need to do something like the following: (not including modules and depedency injection and details may vary depending on UT library and whether you have jQuery or not, but conceptually...)

```
spyOn(MyConfig,'adjusttop').and.returnValue(true);
spyOn($window,'scrollTop').and.returnValue(0);
var element = angular.element("<my-directive></my-directive>");
$scope = $rootScope.$new(); // get a new $scope
$compile(element)($scope); // compile and link the directive
$scope.$digest();
$(window).trigger('scroll'); // to get the scroll event to actually fire

expect($scope.top).toBe(70); // assuming I did the math right???
```